# MouseOver javascript Timeline trigger in Adobe animate

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, adobe, mouseover

I try to create an interactive HTML canvas Animation with the new Adobe Animate (NOT Edge). I can jump to Keyframes on the timeline using the offered code fragment

```
this.movieClip_1.addEventListener("click",
fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame() {
  this.gotoAndStop(29);
}
```

Is there a way to  access the timeline in a similar way using MouseOver instead of MouseClick?
Unfortunately my javascript knowledge is pretty small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.movieClip_1.addEventListener("mouseenter", fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame.bind(this));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: Thank You so much, the link helps a lot to understand what the script is doing. Sorry for being so noob.

Comment: This doesn't work with Adobe Animate projects, because it uses CreateJS and `mouseenter` is not an handled by CreateJS. A correct solution is to use `mouseover` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Animate uses CreateJS, here you can have a list of available mouse interactions: http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/

I quote:

> There are a number of events you can listen for on display objects:
>   click, mousedown, dblclick, pressmove, pressup, mouseover / mouseout,
>   and rollover / rollout.